# Problem with salt-master and salt-minion connection in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, salt-stack

I am having problem in connecting salt-master and salt-minion in latest version ubuntu.
https://bitbucket.org/jmarhee/saltstack-docker/src
I used this reference, but as it was using older version of ubuntu, I updated ubuntu in docker build file. But after updating ubuntu version it doesn't connect with salt-master.

Below are the files. Thanks in advance.

salt_master_docker_file

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget gnupg
RUN wget -O - https://repo.saltstack.com/py3/ubuntu/20.04/amd64/3001/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://repo.saltstack.com/py3/ubuntu/20.04/amd64/latest focal main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y salt-master


EXPOSE 4505 4506

COPY setup.sh /opt/setup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/opt/setup.sh"]
CMD []
```

salt_master_setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

key_checker () {

        x=1
        while [ $x -le 250 ]
                do
                salt-key -A -y
                x=$(( $x + 1 ))
                sleep 1
        done
        echo "All available keys accepted." && salt "*" test.ping && \
        touch /var/log/salt/master && \
        tail -f /var/log/salt/master

}

service salt-master start && key_checker
```

salt_minion_Docker_file

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget gnupg
RUN wget -O - https://repo.saltstack.com/py3/ubuntu/20.04/amd64/3001/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://repo.saltstack.com/py3/ubuntu/20.04/amd64/latest focal main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y salt-minion curl


COPY setup.sh /opt/setup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/opt/setup.sh"]
CMD []
```

salt_minion_setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

salt_minion_check () {
        if [ ! -f /var/log/salt/minion ]; then
          echo "File not found!" && \
          touch /var/log/salt/minion && \
          salt_minion_check
        else
          tail -f /var/log/salt/minion
        fi
}

echo "master: master_1" >> /etc/salt/minion && \
echo "id: salt-minion-$(hostname)" >> /etc/salt/minion

service salt-minion start && \
salt_minion_check
```

main docker-compose-file

```
version: '3'
services:
  minion:
    image: salt-minion
    links:
      - master
    depends_on:
      - master
    networks:
      saltnetwork:
        aliases:
          - minion


  master:
    image: salt-master
    networks:
      saltnetwork:
        aliases:
          - master

networks:
  saltnetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're encountering?  Can you rearrange the images to run a _single_ process as the main container process (make the main container process be `salt-master` or `salt-minion`, and not something else)?

Comment: `echo "master: master_1" >> /etc/salt/minion && \`
In this line we have mentioned that salt-master image that we run will me the master but that is not talking effect. Is there anything I am doing wrong.

Comment: What happens if you change the master container to only run the master, and not the wrapper script?  (In the Dockerfile, change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` and delete the empty `CMD` line; and then `docker run your-image salt-master` to directly run the master instead of the default `CMD`.)

Comment: Yes it will create a independent containter. But my main question is how to accept keys of **salt-minion** from **salt-master** without login into them.

Comment: [github link to docker files](https://github.com/Rjl03/docker_saltstack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Saltstack documentation there is a way to [preseed keys](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/master/topics/tutorials/preseed_key.html) on the master to avoid interactive acceptance.

If all you want to do is bring up a Salt master and a minion with `docker-compose`, something like below should suffice.

Generate `salt-key` on Docker host. This will generate `minion1.pub` and `minion1.pem`.

```
salt-key --gen-keys=minion1
```

Then we will use the respective public and private keys in `Dockerfile`. Example **Salt master** `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gnupg
COPY SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub /tmp/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub
COPY saltstack.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list
RUN apt-key add /tmp/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y salt-master
COPY minion1.pub /etc/salt/pki/master/minions/minion1
```

Example **Salt minion** `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gnupg
COPY SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub /tmp/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub
COPY saltstack.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list
RUN apt-key add /tmp/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y salt-minion

COPY minion1.pem /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
COPY minion1.pub /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub
COPY id.conf /etc/salt/minion.d/id.conf
```

The above `id.conf` is simple:

```
id: minion1
```

By default Salt minions look for `salt` hostname. If it resolves to a Salt master, it is used. So we can leverage this in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  minion1:
    image: myminion
    command: salt-minion

  salt:
    image: mymaster
    command: salt-master
    ports:
      - 4505
      - 4506
```

**Note:**

When we accept a minion's key using `salt-key -A` command, under the hood it moves the minion's public key from `/etc/salt/pki/master/minions_pre/` to `/etc/salt/pki/master/minions` on the master.